# Parsing Error while using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

Let me explain the actual problem I am facing.

When my SearchString is C+, the setup of regular expression below works fine.
However when my searchstring is C++, it throws me an error stating --

```
  parsing "C++" - Nested quantifier +.
```

Can anyone let me know how to get past this error?

```
RegExp = new Regex(Search_Str.Replace(" ", "|").Trim(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Well, you did not post the regex yet :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I believe that you'll learn much more by looking at some regex tutorials instead of asking here at your current stage.

To answer your question, I would like to point out that `+` is a quantifier in regexp, and means 1 or more times the previous character (or group), so that `C+` will match at least 1 `C`, meaning `C` will match, `CC` will match, `CCC` will match and so on. Your search with `C+` is actually matching only `C`!

`C++` in a regex will give you an error, at least in C#. You won't with other regex flavours, including JGsoft, Java and PCRE (`++` is a [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) in those flavours).

So, what to do? You need to escape the `+` character so that your search will look for the literal `+` character. One easy way is to add a backslash before the `+`: `\+`. Another way is to put the `+` in square brackets.

This said, you can use:

```
C\+\+
```

Or...

```
C[+][+]
```

To look for `C++`. Now, since you have twice the same character, you can use `{n}` (where `n` is the number of occurrences) to denote the number of occurrences of the last character, whence:

```
C\+{2}
```

Or...

```
C[+]{2}
```

Which should give the same results.

Comment: Thanks Jerry for the detail explanation. This helped to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 3):

Plus `+` is a special symbol in regular expression. You must escape it.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"C+\+");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Ghost. However can you let me know how to get past this error? How does it allow C+ to go through and not C++?

Comment: @user2604371 `C+` means one or more `C` character (as in `CCCC`).

Answer (score 1):

I could not help but notice @ghost's answer is wrong.

This snippet is wrong:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"C+\+");
```

Because the first + is not escaped. So the meaning still is "one or more `C` characters followed by a plus sign". The correct form would be `@"C\+\+"`